# Backgroundwork in C# foreach loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker

I have a situation where in UI thread i want to uninstall all MSI from my machine (MSI uninstall string can be obtained from registry HKLM\software\Microsfot\CurrentVersion\Uninstall).

Now in my UI i am uninstalling MSI using process.start(0 and process.exit() in background worker. my way to implement:
1. On button click event get the list of MSI to be uninstaled by parsing the registry.
2. now in foreach loop uninstall MSI one by one.
3. After uninstall disaply message "Uninstall success!" in RichText box window.
My problem:  When one MSI uninstall is in progress (backgroundworker is running in background) , GUI disaplay "Uninstall success" and proceed for 2nd MSI.

Note: I know this can be blocked using lock but i want my GUI to be idle (do nothing) until one MSI uninstall finish -> display message and then process for 2nd MSI.

Please help. alternatively please suggest other way to implement the same (without freezing the UI).

```
namespace TestGUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            string arg = (string)e.Argument;
            ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startinfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startinfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe"
            startinfo.Arguments = arg;
            Process ISscript = new Process();
            try
            {
                ISscript = Process.Start(startinfo);

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exp.Message);
            }
            int progress = 1;
            string statusText = "Background Worker Is In Progress ...";
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(progress, statusText);
            ISscript.WaitForExit();

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //label1.Text = (string)e.UserState;
            int number = (int)e.ProgressPercentage;
            DP.Text = number.ToString();
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                DP.Text = "Error while performing background operation.";
            }
            else
            {  
                // Everything completed normally.
                DP.Text = "Task Completed...";
            }

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string s in UninstString)
            {
            string arg = s;
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(arg);


            DP.AppendText("Uninstall completed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just move the foreach loop into DoWork and pass UninstString instead, easy peasy.

Comment: Understood but ca i update the Rich Textbox in UI from background worker thread? e.g. "Uninstall start for <product name>, Uninstall failed, Uninstall success etc.???

Comment: You already know how to do that with ReportProgress.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.    Just for knowledge purpose is there any alternate way to get this done.

Comment: You can also ditch the backgroundworker and use `Task.Run`. Makes your code alot cleaner

Comment: sorry i forget to mention that i am using .net 3.5, hence task.run cannot be possible. other options, please?

Comment: Why do you have to do this through C#? msicuu and msizap are two perfectly fine command line utilities.